# How do I create multiple instances of same exe in c# to pass different inputs to the exe at same time

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, console-application, multiple-instances

I have developed a console application in C# which takes file path as input and converts the file at the location to PDF format.

I need to do the conversion for 20000 files whose information will be present in a dataset, the approach is to split the load into 4 sets, 5000 records in each dataset and create 4 instances of the console application executable and pass the dataset as input.

I need the console application instances to run parallely to achieve the output fast and making use of the available CPU.

The total files to be converted is 2 Million and hence planning to convert them in batches of 20000.

Could someone please help me on the approach to create multiple instance of same exe file and run them in parallel. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you considered only running the console application once, and then handling all the parallel processing within C#?

Comment: @Bhrath Chandra why dont you use parallel programming using Parallel.Invoke?

Comment: It's easeir and *faster* to use an [ActionBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-perform-action-when-a-dataflow-block-receives-data) with a DOP of 4, post all records to it and have the CLR process it them parallel. Or you can create a pipeline of blocks, each of them running on a separate task.

Comment: Bad idea. You will not gain anything. The bottleneck will be IO operations. Only one task will be able to load and only one to save result (assuming 2 different storages are used). Is there "parallel" storage?

Comment: Four instances of the same app with different path parameters, works on Windows: `start app.exe "path1" & start app.exe "path2" & start app.exe "path3" & start app.exe "path4"`

Comment: @Sinatr on the contrary, even with a single disk buffering means that you *can* get performance improvements by parallelism. PDF generation is CPU intensive too, which means it will benefit from parallelism. A pipeline of blocks that iterate files, process them and write them out to the final target will run faster than a single console application

Comment: In fact, even a crude `Parallel.ForEach(fileList,file=>ConvertToPDF(file))` could improve performance for a relatively small number of files. For 2M files, *iterating* them is expensive enough that it would have to be performed as a separate step.

Comment: It all depends on type of storage being used for obtaining the files and where the files are to be saved. If reading from and writing to a magnetic HD, one thread to do both the reading and writing, and (#Cores-1) of other threads to do the processing.

Comment: @MineR The source and target folders are in a network file share(Magentic HD), file need to be extracted from source folder then converted to PDF and must be placed in target folder with in the same file share

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos The problem statement is to utilize CPU at max possible levels and perform the conversion process as fast as we can. Will you be able to suggest if using Parallel.ForEach and running multiple instances of exe are same at performance. If running multiple exe files in parallel will yield better results, I'm looking for help on the syntax or approach to create multiple instance of a same exe. Could you please suggest me on this.

Comment: @BharathChandra multiple executables have a higher overhead than multiple threads. You don't need multiple executables. PLINQ, `Parallel.ForEach` actually partition the data based on the number of cores so you don't have to. Blocks allow you to specify how many files to process in parallel. All are (far) easier and faster than using multiple executables

Comment: @BharathChandra besides, the problem isn't really how fast you can process 2M files. You'll *definitely* get errors in 2M files so you'll need to be able to continue processing even after an error, move processed files to an `archive` folder, error files to another location so you can retry them etc. It's easier to do this if you can create a pipeline of processing blocks.

Comment: @BharathChandra the *cmd* command line can't batch or process files in parallel. Powershell on the other hand *can* combine commands and runs each step in a separate thread. The [ForEach -Parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1) can spawn multiple threads to process the input files in parallel

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs, I shall analyse on using Parallel.ForEach which seems to be a bit easier and efficient